# Decrement metric in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, decrement

Is it possible to decrement metric in GA? I am using GA through GTM and here is a tag in which I tried to decrement the metric, but it did not change my metric. I checked that custom metric does not have the minimum or maximum value set.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like google analytics doesn't handle negative integers in custom metrics. However, there is a workaround. You may set the additional custom metric for "decreased" amount of your value and then use a 'calculated' metric with a formula like: calc_metric = base_metic - decreased_amount 
More on calculated metrics https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en